# Function not writing to required cell following array calculation ; excel vba userforms

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, userform

I am new to vba and need some help please.
I have a function whose role is to write to a cell a text value depending on a certain condition.

'input to the function will be a string obtained from a combobox within a userform.  The Rowarray is an array of 53 cells with values of either "1's" or "".

```
    Function State(ID As String, Rowarray() As String) 

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Rej As String
    Dim Vir As String
    Dim Result As Variant
    Dim Rng
    Dim Rngrow As Integer
    Dim Arr

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Temp")

    Set Rng = ws.Columns(5).Find(ID).Address 'obtains the address of a cell with a value matching the combobox value.
    Rngrow = ws.Range(Rng).row 'Obtains the row number from address above
    Rej = "R"
    Vir = "V"
    Arr = Rowarray()

    Result = ws.Cells(Rngrow, 6).Value 'this cell is where output is to be placed - one column adjacent to the ID cell (same row)


        'conditional statements determining what goes into result cell
        If Len(Arr) >= 1 Then

        Result = Rej

        ElseIf Len(Arr) < 1 Then

        Result = Vir

        Else

        Result = Vir

        End If

End Function
```

Since the array 'Arr' will only have values of "1's" or "", the condition tests whether the array will have anything in it at all.  If one element of the array is occupied by a "1" - the result is Rej.  Only if all the elements of the array 'Arr' contain "" do I want the result to be Vir.

My problem is that the function is not writing to the 'Result' cell.  Is there anything that I am doing wrong?  Is my problem with how excel arrays read "" strings?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Add `State = Result` before ending the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function never writes to the *result* cell because you actually never tell it to write to the cell.

This line `Result = ws.Cells(Rngrow, 6).Value` only sets the variable Result to the value existing in the specific cell at the time the code is run.

Your `If` block then just resets the `Result` variable.

See the below code, which I think is more in line with what you want. I added code to loop through the array and check for `1`, and then set the value in the result cell based on what's in the array. I also added better variable qualifying to match types. I also made this a `Sub` since it does not return any value, like a `Function` would.

```
Sub State(ID As String, Rowarray() As String)

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Rej As String, Vir As String
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Rngrow As Integer
    Dim Arr() As String

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Temp")

    Set Rng = ws.Columns(5).Find(ID) 'obtains the cell with a value matching the combobox value.

    If Not Rng Is Nothing Then

        Rngrow = Rng.Row 'Obtains the row number from range above

        Rej = "R"
        Vir = "V"

        Arr() = Rowarray()

        Dim l As Long, bRej As Boolean

        For l = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)

            If Arr(l) = "1" Then
                ws.Cells(Rngrow, 6).Value = Rej
                bRej = True
                Exit For
            End If

        Next

        If Not bRej Then ws.Cells(Rngrow, 6).Value = Vir

    Else

        ws.Cells(Rngrow, 6).Value = "id not found"

    End If

End Sub
```

One more note, I looped through the array because each array has an element. Even if that element = `""`. So you cannot just use Len(Arr) to test the whole case. You have to test each element in the array against your criteria.

Comment: Thanks @ Scott Holtzman.  Your logic makes sense.  However, I have come across a runtime error '424': Object required with this line     Set Rng = ws.Columns(5).Find(DieID).Address

Comment: You seem to have added the letters `Die` by accident in `Find(DieID)` That is not in the code in your OP or my answer. And get rid of the `.Address` in the line. I will edit my answer for that.

Comment: Thanks Scott.  Apologies about the 'Die' addition - I am working on two pieces of code at one time.  The `Set Rng = ws.Columns(5).Find(ID).Address` is the correct line.  The `.Address` is required as the `Rngrow` variable extracts the row number from the address.  This has been an issue before, and cannot figure out why??

Comment: Keep the .`Address` out because I set `rng` as `Range` variable and `.Address` is a string property.. I changed the line to get the row to reflect this as well ... `Rngrow = rng.Row`

Comment: (A BIG sigh of relief) - Thanks Scott.  Works like an absolute charm! Legend.